# Can't Create Contact Form in MVC 3

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to create a simple contact form.  Here is my model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

Public Class Contact

    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Title() As String
    Public Property Company() As String
    Public Property CompanyAddress() As String
    Public Property PhoneNumber() As String
    Public Property NumberOfEmployees() As String
    Public Property EmailAddress() As String
    Public Property Subject() As String
    Public Property Message() As String

End Class
```

Here is my View:

```
@ModelType MyBlog.Contact
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = ViewBag.Title
End Code
@Using Html.BeginForm()

    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.EmailAddress)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.EmailAddress)

    @<input type="submit" value="Send" />

End Using
```

And, here is my controller:

```
Function Contact() As ActionResult

    Return View("", "_FinalSubPageLayout", "")

End Function
```

The error I get is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyBlog.Contact'.

What can I do to resolve this error?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 'Return View("", "_FinalSubPageLayout", "")

  Dim myModel as New Blog.Contact
  'fill myModel

  Return View("", "_FinalSubPageLayout", myModel)
```

I'm not sure about that first `""`, you may need to specify the actual name or pass Nothing or something.

Comment: Thank you, but it is not a variable.  It is a layout name `_FinalSubPageLayout.vbhtml`.  You can substitute it for `View()` which will render the view with the same error (just not inside a layout).

Comment: Really good catch, guys.  I didn't realize I had to send the model there.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `""` as model to your view which expects a model of type `MyBlog.Contact`. Not sure off the top of my head which of those two `""` arguments should be the model, but you need to make it an instance of `MyBlog.Contact` or use an overload that doesn't require the model.

Comment: Really good catch, guys.  I didn't realize I had to send the model there.